# Flutter different duration for different Animation

Tags: dart, flutter

**Code**

```
// Member variables
AnimationController _controller;
Animation _animation1;
Animation _animation2;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  );

  _animation1 = Tween<double>(begin: 0.2, end: 1).animate(_controller);
  _animation2 = Tween<double>(begin: 0.4, end: 1).animate(_controller);
}
```

Here both `_animation1` and `_animation2` gets `400` milliseconds of duration. However I want to change the duration for `_animation2`. How can I do that without creating a new `AnimationController`.

Comment: You can't. You have to create a new controller. Although you can cheat a bit with curves

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks, I know I can play with curves having slower in beginning and faster later. (Have to check which one suits this, probably, `EaseOut`

Comment: [Interval](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/Interval-class.html) is closer to your needs

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thank you so much for the hint, I remember I used it few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

`Interval` as suggested by Rémi is the solution.

```
_animation1 = Tween<double>(begin: 0.2, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
  parent: _controller,
  curve: Interval(0.5, 1.0),
));
_animation2 = Tween<double>(begin: 0.2, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
  parent: _controller,
  curve: Interval(0.8, 1.0),
));
```